# Ranchers cattle-cluster-agent-* pod log errors

Tags: kubernetes, helm, rancher

When deploying rancher onto a downstream cluster the cattle-cluster-agent- pods appear and they show running. The issue is (1) when I try to access the cluster via the UI, the UI displayed "  Cluster agent is not connected" and I cannot manage the clutser. (2) Using the kubectl, I run the command `kubectl get cattle-cluster-agent-*********-*****` and the following error shows (some info in the log entry has been redacted for security purposes):

```
time="2023-08-29T15:52:48Z" level=error msg="error syncing 'random-namespace/sh.helm.release.v1.name-of-chart.v1': handler helm-app-secret: failed to create random-namespace/name-of-chart catalog.cattle.io/v1, Kind=App for helm-app random-namespace/sh.helm.release.v1.name-of-chart.v1: rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = trying to send message larger than max (2330208 vs. 2097152), requeuing"
```

I am trying to figure out how to resolve this rpc error. Where is the call / file that is to large coming from? Is there a config setting I can change to resolve this?

I have already tried redeploying the deployment that creates those pods and that has done nothing. I can see the secrets that it refers to and the byte size is well below the limit.

Any ideas would be great. Thank you